# How do I print a taxonomy term in node.tpl.php? (D7)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a custom content type that I can select a vocab term for when editing the page (category more or less). How do I print this term to my page via node.tpl.php?

I've tried several different ways, but to no avail so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php print render($content['field_tags']); ?>
```

Comment: Oh geez duh, just like I'm printing every other field... I'm not sure why something so obvious escaped me ;-) Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it works! Welcome.